# How to make html reference to link in java

Tags: java, html, hyperlink

I have a code written in java like string say

```
String link = "<a href=\"https://jira.com/browse/\" target=\"_blank\">TICKET-NUMBER</a>";
```

When I run it the output is https://jira.com/browse/TICKET_NUMBER.When I click on this ,it will take me to jira
But since the http link is common and the ticket number is dynamic ,I want only the ticketnumber to be shown as hyperlink rather than the entire link.
When I click on TICKET NUMBER ,it should take me to jira directly

Comment: Do you have that ticket number in a variable? If yes, let's assume this variable is called `myVariableTicketNumber`, you can concatenate the link by `String link = <a href=\"https://jira.com/browse/\" target=\"_blank\">" + myVariableTicketNumber + "</a>";`?

Comment: There's also a missing `"` at the beginning:`String link = "<a href=\"https://jira.com/browse/\" target=\"_blank\">TICKET-NUMBER</a>";` . If you need the value of ticket number instead of a "TICKET-NUMBER" see the comment above, the same can be applied if the value goes in the url.

Comment: Yes!! I have a variable.I think you didnot get my question.The output is https://jira.com/browse/myvairableTicketNumber and when I click on it ,it will take me to the concerned page.But I want to hide the jira link in the output,I want only the myvariableTicketNumber to be as output which when clicked should take me to jira

Comment: That's just a writing mistake @Harpistry

Comment: Can someone help me on this?